# How do I have python run (if statements) based on the users input.?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not doing anything particularly complicated I am simply messing with import random and having the user type roll to roll a six sided die. I have gotten this far.

```
import random

roll = random.randint(1,6)

input("Type roll to roll the dice!\n")

# This is where I have my issue pass this line I'm trying things out, unsuccessfully.
if (userInput) == (roll)

    print("\n" + str(roll))
else:
    input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

I don't want the program to print the `str(roll)` if the use presses enter, I'd rather it exit the program if no input is given. So how do I write the code to do particular thing based of user input when using the if statement. If user input is `'roll"` then `print("str(roll))`?

Comment: You don't seem to have saved `userInput`. That `if` statement also ends without a colon, which is a syntax error. Does your code appear exactly like this?

Comment: You also seem to be confusing the saved variable name `roll` with the string `'roll'`. You might consider reviewing your textbook or other course material first.

Comment: Yes it does. I need to read more on userInput. I was just trying things. Good catch on the syntax error. My apologies.

Comment: You might want to read a tutorial,  this is very basic. http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/

Comment: Thank you for the reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to capture the user input in a variable. Currently, the return value of `input(…)` is being thrown away. Instead, store it in `userInput`:

   ```
   userInput = input("Type roll to roll the dice!\n")
   ```
2. The `if` requires a colon at the end in order to start the block:

   ```
   if someCondition:
   #               ^
   ```
3. If you want to compare the user input against the string `'roll'`, then you need to specify that as a string, and not as a (non-existent) variable:

   ```
   if userInput == 'roll':
   ```

   You also don’t need parentheses around the values
4. In order to check for just an enter press, check against the empty string:

   ```
   elif userInput == '':
       print('User pressed enter without entering stuff')
   ```
5. You should roll inside the condition, not before, so you don’t generate a random number although it’s not requested.

So in total, it could look like this:

```
import random

userInput = input('Type roll to roll the dice!\n')

if userInput == 'roll':
    roll = random.randint(1,6)
    print('You rolled: ', roll)
elif userInput == '':
    print('Exit')
```

Comment: Thanks poke, I learned from your comment. I just started my programming class and I was jumping ahead because I find it very interesting. So maybe I jumped the gun to quickly. Thank you for breaking down the code and explaining it.